# Recover important boot files?

Tags: boot

I deleted important boot files.
How do i recover them.
When i boot there is coming the error NTLDR missing.

http://postimg.org/image/hj5fjdgyx/

i used the mashine in the beginning with two systems. windows on the 1st and ubuntu on the 2nd. Later i deleted windows to get space.

What can i do to recover!?

Answer (score 0):

If the only file you are missing is NTLDR, you can download it [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8JoV2w_9hicMjFNcm5xY1ViYmc/edit?usp=sharing). You can then paste it into the boot files on the C: drive of your Windows partition.

Caveat: This is an NTLDR file I pulled from a previous windows installation. I haven't used it in a while, but it should work.

> > As a general rule, I include the warning that downloading unknown files from people you don't know personally, particularly to install an application or alter a critical file, is not a good security practice.
> >      That said... you can at least take comfort in the fact that I am a member in good standing for over a year, with no history of malicious activity.

Comment: If you have another Windows machine, you should also be able to boot to the live CD on the working machine, copy NTLDR from that machine to a USB drive, and then copy from the USB drive to your problem machine. This way you're not taking candy from strangers. :)